# Main Drive Not Listed on Boot Priority Menu - Asus

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I've recently installed a drive that runs Linux but wanted to maintain Windows as my default boot drive. This hasn't happened and after tooling around in the BIOS for a bit, and doing some research, I can't seem to find a way to get it back.

My main drive, a Kingston SSD, isn't showing up in the boot priority menu, but does show up in the boot override menus both on the EZ screen and advanced. 
Does anyone know how I get it there?

[image: pic of boot priority menu]

Comment: Could you have overwritten the Windows boot loader?  Did you install Linux to the same drive as Windows?

Comment: They're on two separate drives, but I did unplug the Windows drive during the Linux install just to be safe. Not sure if that's recommended or not - could that be the cause?

Comment: No and it is recommended. Disconnect the drive that has Linux on it.